# Convert decimal to sign and magnitude binary form

Tags: binary, bit

I want to convert -95 to sign/magnitude form using 12 bits.

Would it be 000001011111 for magnitude and an extra 1 bit to the left of the last 1 to make it negative?

=> `000011011111`

I wasn't sure whether to put the sign bit all the way on the left (the MSB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSB as sign bit is a good choice. Languages like C do the same.

Comment: so there isn't a "correct" answer? you can put the sign bit anywhere to the left of the magnitude bits?

Comment: technically yes...(as long its consistent location) but it really make sense to use the MSB for sign and rest for the magnitude. Its a cleaner soln and easy to work with.